# How to do both internal and external .htacces rewrite to completely remove ALL QUERY_STRING elements from ALL URIs, with relative path

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to remove all client request querystrings whatsoever, no exceptions.
I have tried everything I can find, and everything I know about regular expressions, and this task puzzles me. I have been able to achieve removal of the query strings, but now all requests have the full file path prepended to the working directory upon rewrite and redirect.

Examples: there is no http in these because stackoverflow won't let me post URLs.

I access the file: /localhost/testing/dogs/pups.txt
Yes, pups.txt exists and lives right there.

Server returns this to browser: /localhost/home/user/public_html/testing/dogs/pups.txt

If I access it with a query string appended:
/localhost/testing/dogs/pups.txt?bark=woof

I get the same output to the browser:
/localhost/home/gost/public_html/testing/dogs/pups.txt

So I know the query string is being nixed, while the full root path is being added to the hypertext address.

How do I tell mod_rewrite to keep the relative path of the existing files, so that this prepending of the full file path stops, and accurately cause it to rewrite internally and externally so that no query string ever makes it to php-land?

Here is the current .htaccess file. It resides in directory /home/user/public_html/testing. Where deployed online, it is NOT possible to put it in the root web directory, the obvious move that would instantly resolve this problem.

```
# These are commented out on purpose because they kill access to the server.
    # The weird rules for regex in Apache configurations is baffling me. This
    # does remove all QUERY_STRING characters, but, it then rewrites by 
    # prepending the web root path to the current directory, causing error 404.

    # RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^
    # RewriteRule  (.*) $1? [R=301,L]

    # These rules work fine. Whatever does not end with a media or document
    # extension gets sent to index.php

    RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|txt|svg|pdf|rtf|odt|doc|docx)$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^.*\.(tex|epub|mobi|csv|ods|xls|swf|flv)$ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Add a rewritebase above the rules `RewriteBase /testing` and put these rules in the testing folder .htaccess. Also I would change the query string condition to this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .` So that it does any character. Right now you have it as start with nothing.

Comment: Thank you, you are right that RewriteBase would help, and I should have mentionded the host has totally disabled RewriteBase in .htaccess files. When I use "." instead of "^" all urls of existing files and directories return error 404 even when the rewrite is not applied.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about your host. The other thing you can do is put the path in the rule. `RewriteRule ^ /testing/index.php [L]` And using `.` should not break anything. It should only match if there is a query_string.  Plus you have that rule commented out. Same with this rule `RewriteRule  (.*) /testing/$1? [R=301,L]`

Comment: @Panama Jack That did the trick. Now all test requests with a query string have the query string stripped both internally and externally. I set up a PHP script to intercept and echo the the URLs that mod_rewrite delivers and they are all cleaned up. It's working flawlessly. I still don't understand why mod_rewrite appends without the directory name being coded into the rule, and why it doesn't append root path with the directory name keyed in. To me mod_rewrite is trickier than a high-level language. Thanks for sharing the super moo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^` to this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .`
and add the directory to the rule since you can't use rewritebase. So it should look like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /testing/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't accept my own answer for two days, so if anyone wants to add logic about mod_rewrite for future questioners, have at it. Per Panama Jack's advice, this .htaccess file does the job and this question is answered.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /testing/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|txt|svg|pdf|rtf|odt|doc|docx)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(tex|epub|mobi|csv|ods|xls|mm|)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ test.php [L]
```